# Heroku Postgresql with Google Datastudio II

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, looker-studio

I refer to this post: 
[Heroku Postgresql with Google Datastudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386975/heroku-postgresql-with-google-datastudio#new-answer?newreg=1e27532e199e434283c25a4f7e01732c) - does anyone have an idea when ssl support for postres will start or if there is a good workaround?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is already support for SSL connections using GDS. Here is another thread referecing the way to go: [Heroku Postgresql with Google Datastudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386975/heroku-postgresql-with-google-datastudio)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).