# How to connect a Google Data Studio Data Source to Azure Postgres with SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, looker-studio

There are not really good tutorials on Google Data Studio to use SSL with non-Google setups.

Azure is even less documented.

I found this for Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security

There they provide the sslrootcert for the server BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem for download.

This doesn't help with the setup of the Data Source. Where normally I would expect a SSL = true feature, Google Data Studio requires a full certificate offering rather than figuring it out itself.

There are no useful error messages.

Flipping of SSL on the Postgres server works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours if trial and error and reading outdated forum posts, I have realized that Google Data Studio is just asking for a client key. You can really use whatever you want.

I followed the instructions on this post [Heroku Postgresql with Google Datastudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386975/heroku-postgresql-with-google-datastudio)

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client.key -x509 -days 365 -out client.crt
```

[image]

Then it will export a `client.crt` and a `client.key` that you can upload to the Google Data Studio. This is along with the `BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem` that was referenced in the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security).

NOTE you will want to create a new/unique `client.crt` and `client.key` for each Data Source.

Comment: Also, for others who still struggle with this, make sure you added the GDS ip addresses to your firewall. https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343

Comment: Hey, is this currently still working for you? I get errors with the Server cert which is supposedly replacing the Baltimore one. :/