# Connecting Heroku Postgres to Google Studio Looker

Tags: heroku, looker-studio, heroku-postgres, looker

I'm trying to connect a Heroku Postgres database to Google Looker Studio (former Data Studio).

I found an old stack overflow question that suggests I need to use SSL and for that I need to enable certificates:

[Heroku Postgresql with Google Datastudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386975/heroku-postgresql-with-google-datastudio)

I am using my production database which has Standard-0 plan.

I created a follower database.

I enabled enhanced certificates on the follower database as described in [Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-enhanced-certificates):

```
heroku plugins:install data

heroku data:labs:enable enhanced-certificates  --app village-api-prod --addon=postgresql-round-48019
```

However, it's not clear to me where to get the certificate that Studio looker is asking for when SSL option is selected.

I tried the python script suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994943/6342826) and selected the generated certificate but it still gives me an error. (I'm not too familiar with how SSL and certificates work, so I barely understand what this script does.)

```
python postgres_get_server_cert.py postgres://(redacted)@34-foobar.data.elastic.heroku.com:5432 > aws-cert.crt
```

[image]

I saw this support article but it doesn't get past me here https://help.heroku.com/3DELT3RK/why-can-t-my-third-party-utility-connect-to-heroku-postgres-with-ssl

How should I get a certificate?

Might the problem be that I'm using a follower database?
I'm losing it, I can't believe it's that hard

Comment: Additional tip: By the way, to get a quik and easy instance of Python 2 going, use Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should download the ISRG Root X1 from Lets Encrypt and use that as the SSL certificate.

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

[image: lets encrypt]

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can this be used? Do I somehow add it on heroku side?